# не видит контекста (ctx ) в canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

````
Игровое поле нарисовано в `canvas`, по нему отрисовываются фигурки, но при рендеринге пишет ошибку, что не видит контекст `canvas`.

    file index.html
    ```<body>
    <div class="modal">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <span class="btn">
                    <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                </span>
                    <p class="alert-text">
                    </p>
                    <p class="rules">Rules of game</p>

            </div>
       </div>
    <script src="js/resources.js"></script>
    <!-- <script src="js/app.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/appUpdate.js"></script>
    <script src="js/engine.js"></script>```
    file appUpdate.js
     '''const enemiesSprite = [
    'images/enemy-bug.png',
    'images/enemy-bug_invert.png'
    ];
    console.dir(enemiesSprite);
    const playerList = [
    'images/char-boy.png',
    'images/char-cat-girls.png',
    'images/char-horn-girl.png',
    'images/char-pink-girl.png',
    'images/char-princess-girl.png'
    ];

    let allEnemies = [],
    dt,
    speed,
    player,
    image,
    dx,
    dy,
    firstPosition,
    deltaPosition,
    maxGameboard,
    counterLife = 5,
    counterCollision = 0,
    maxPosition = {
        x : 1506,
        y : 1205
    }; //actual position y 400

    //ctx;


    // Enemies our player must avoid
    // Variables applied to each of our instances go here,
    // we've provided one for you to get started

    // The image/sprite for our enemies, this uses
    // a helper we've provided to easily load images
    class Enemy{
    constructor(x, y, speed){
        this.sprite = 'images/enemy-bug.png';
        this.setEnemyY(y);
        this.setEnemyX(x);
        this.speed = speed;
    }

    setEnemyY(y){
        // Enemy's Y coordinate stays the same during the game run
        this.y = y;
        this.y1 = this.y + 78;
        this.y2 = this.y1 + 66;
    }

    setEnemyX(x){
        this.x = x;
        // (x1,y1) - left upper point of the bug figure
        this.x1 = this.x + 2;
        // (x2,y2) - right lower point of the bug figure
        this.x2 = this.x1 + 96;
    }

    checkCoordinats(x,y,speed){
        if (this.x >=1506){
            this.x = -100;
            this.speed = Math.round((Math.random()*250) + (Math.random()*250)); //actual version
            //console.log("enemy came out for edge");
        }
    }

    // Update the enemy's position, required method for game
    // Parameter: dt, a time delta between ticks
    update (dt){
        // You should multiply any movement by the dt parameter
        // which will ensure the game runs at the same speed for
        // all computers.
        // Enemy moves only to the right, y coordinate stays the same.
        this.setEnemyX(this.x + dt * this.speed);
        this.checkCoordinats();

    }
    // Draw the enemy on the screen, required method for game
    render(){
        //console.log(this.sprite);
        ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
        }
    }



class Player {
    constructor(x, y){
        // actual char-boy.png figure width = 68 px, height = 75 px
        this.sprite = 'images/char-boy.png';
        this.setPlayerCoordinates(x,y);
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
        this.counterLife = counterLife;
        this.counterCollision = counterCollision;
    }

    setPlayerCoordinates(x,y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        // (x1,y1) - left upper point of the boy figure
        this.x1 = this.x + 19;
        this.y1 = this.y + 80;// actual position +64
        // (x2,y2) - left upper point of the boy figure
        this.x2 = this.x1 + 68;
        this.y2 = this.y1 + 61;// actual height +75
    }

    getNewPosition(position, maxGameboard){
        //console.log(allowedKeys);
    if (position == this.x){
        maxGameboard = maxPosition.x;
    } else {
        maxGameboard = maxPosition.y;
    }

        if (position<= -80 || position >= maxGameboard){

            this.x = 703;
            this.y = 1130;

        }
    }
    checkContactWithWater(x,y){
        if (this.y > 839 && this.y < 1005){
            console.log('contact with water');
            console.log ('=======================');
        } else if(this.y < 125){ `введите сюда код`
            console.log('contact with water');
            counterLife += 1;
            //console.log(counterLife);
            this.x = 400;
            this.y = 715;
            return counterLife;
        }
    }

    checkCollisionSideByPlayer(){
        //console.log(player.x1, player.x2);
        for(let enemy of allEnemies){
          // Here was the error !!!!!
          //if(!(enemy.x2 < this.x1 || enemy.x2 > this.x2)){
            if(!(enemy.x2 < this.x1 || enemy.x1 > this.x2)){
                if(!(enemy.y2 < this.y1 || enemy.y1 > this.y2)){
                    //console.log(`enemy__x2: ${Math.round(enemy.x2)} >= ${Math.round(this.x1)} :player_x1`);
                    //console.log(``);
                    //console.log(`player_x2: ${Math.round(this.x2)} >= ${Math.round(enemy.x1)} :enemy__x1`);
                    //console.log(``);
                    console.log('================================================')
                    this.setPlayerCoordinates(703,1130);
                }

            }
        }
    }

    update(){
        this.setPlayerCoordinates(this.x + this.dx,this.y + this.dy);
        this.checkContactWithWater();
        this.getNewPosition(this.x, maxPosition.x);
        this.getNewPosition(this.y, maxPosition.y);
        this.checkCollisionSideByPlayer();
        this.dx = 0;
        this.dy = 0;
    }

    render(){
        ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);

    }


    handleInput(allowedKeys){
        // player's movement
        // if allowedKeys = 37, move to left
        //console.log(allowedKeys);
        if(true && allowedKeys == "up"){
            this.dy += -83;
        } else if(true && allowedKeys == "down"){
            this.dy += 83;
        } else if(true && allowedKeys == "left"){
            this.dx += -101;
        } else if (true && allowedKeys == "right"){
            this.dx += 101;
        }
    }

}
//add to gamefield Stone
class Stone {
    constructor(x,y,sprite){
        this.sprite = 'images/stone-block.png';
        this.setStoneOX(x);
        this.setStoneOY(y);
   }

    setStoneOX(x){
        this.x = x;
        this.x1 = this.x+4;  //actual position of figure stone by OX
        this.x2 = this.x+93;
    }

    setStoneOY(y){
        this.y = y;
        this.y1 = this.x+58;  //actual position of fige stone by OY
        this.y2 = this.y+103;
    }


    render(){
        //console.log(this.sprite);
        ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);
    }
}

class Rock {
    constructor(x, y){
        this.sprite = 'images/Rock.png';
        this.setRockY(y);
        this.setRockX(x);


    }
     setRockY(y){
        // Enemy's Y coordinate stays the same during the game run
        this.y = y;
        this.y1 = this.y + 67;
        this.y2 = this.y1 + 155;
    }

    setRockX(x){
        this.x = x;
        // (x1,y1) - left upper point of the bug figure
        this.x1 = this.x + 9;
        // (x2,y2) - right lower point of the bug figure
        this.x2 = this.x1 + 92;

    }
    render(){
        console.log (this.ctx);
        ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(this.sprite), this.x, this.y);

    }

}
player = new Player(703, 1130);
let enemy = new Enemy(enemiesSprite[0],-100, 801, 350);
let enemy2 = new Enemy(-100, 561, 275);
let enemy3 = new Enemy(-100, 626, 400);
let enemy4 = new Enemy(-100, 712, 300);
let enemy5 = new Enemy(1505, 712, -350);

let stone = new Stone(106, 48);
let rock = new Rock(300, 500);
//rock.render(ctx);

allEnemies.push(enemy);
allEnemies.push(enemy2);
allEnemies.push(enemy3);
allEnemies.push(enemy4);
allEnemies.push(enemy5);```
file engine.js
```var Engine = (function(global) {

    var doc = global.document,
        win = global.window,
        canvas = doc.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        lastTime;

    canvas.width = 1515; //actual position of canvas width 505;
    canvas.height = 1515; //actual position of canvas width 606;
    doc.body.appendChild(canvas);


    function main() {

        var now = Date.now(),
            dt = (now - lastTime) / 1000.0;


        update(dt);
        render();


        lastTime = now;


        win.requestAnimationFrame(main);
    }

    function init() {
        reset();
        lastTime = Date.now();
        main();
    }

    function update(dt) {
        updateEntities(dt);
        //checkCollisions();
    }

    //function checkCollisions(){
      // console.log(allEnemies);
   // }


    function updateEntities(dt) {
        allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
            enemy.update(dt);
        });
        player.update();
        //console.log(player.x, enemy.x);
    }

    function render() {
        /* This array holds the relative URL to the image used
         * for that particular row of the game level.
         */
        var rowImages = [
                'images/grass-block.png',   // Row 1 of 2 of secondgrass
                'images/water-block.png',   // Row 1 is 2 water
                'images/water-block.png',   // Row 2 is 2 water
                'images/grass-block.png',   // Row 1 of 2 of firstgrass
                'images/grass-block.png',   // Row 2 of 2 of firstgrass
                'images/water-block.png',   // Row 1 is 2 water
                'images/water-block.png',   // Row 2 is 2 water
                'images/stone-block.png',   // Row 1 of 4 of stone
                'images/stone-block.png',   // Row 2 of 4 of stone
                'images/stone-block.png',   // Row 3 of 4 of stone
                'images/stone-block.png',   // Row 4 of 4 of stone
                'images/water-block.png',   // Row 1 is 2 water
                'images/water-block.png',   // Row 2 is 2 water
                'images/grass-block.png',   // Row 1 of 2 of secondgrass
                'images/grass-block.png'    // Row 2 of 2 of secondgrass
            ],
            numRows = 15,//actual position 6
            numCols = 15, //actual position 5
            row, col;

        // Before drawing, clear existing canvas
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width,canvas.height)

        for (row = 0; row < numRows; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < numCols; col++) {

                ctx.drawImage(Resources.get(rowImages[row]), col * 101, row  * 83);
            }
        }

        renderEntities();
    }

        allEnemies.forEach(function(enemy) {
            enemy.render();
        });

        //player.render();
        player.render();
        //rock.render();
    }


    function reset() {
        // noop
    }
    Resources.load([
        'images/stone-block.png',
        'images/water-block.png',
        'images/grass-block.png',
        'images/enemy-bug.png',
        'images/char-boy.png'
    ]);
    Resources.onReady(init);


    global.ctx = ctx;
    })(this);```
````

Comment: весь код тут: https://github.com/Natanagar/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game/tree/newversion

Comment: А почему он должен его видеть? Вы даже переменную такую не объявляете. https://github.com/Natanagar/frontend-nanodegree-arcade-game/blob/newversion/js/appUpdate.js#L31

Comment: переменная обьявляется (она в движке), поле рисуется, не рисуются фигурки

Comment: ``` var doc = global.document,
        win = global.window,
        canvas = doc.createElement('canvas'),
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
        lastTime;```

Comment: Ну так в движке она объявляется, а в файле где у вас 
`class Player` её нет. можете вместо `ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')` написать `window.ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')` и тогда она будет глобально доступна

Comment: в движке эта переменная глобально доступна ``` global.ctx = ctx;```, поле отрисовывается, игрок тоже, а вот враги частично нет(((